Не работают якорные ссылки на блок из вкладок Wordpress
Дорабатываю сайт на Wordpress, https://aquasklad.ru/
На нем размещен блок Акции(ID=tab1)/Хиты(ID=tab2)/Рекомендуем(ID=tab3) состоящий из трех вкладок

В bottom есть раздел "Советуем", где "Акции" и "Хиты" ведут на тот блок из трех вкладок (по ссылкам https://aquasklad.ru/#tab1 и https://aquasklad.ru/#tab2

Проблема в том, что при переходе по ссылке "Акции", меня переводит на этот блок из вкладок, но при переходе по ссылке "Хиты", ничего не происходит. Как это возможно настроить?

Вероятно же в Ваших табах есть лиснер на клик в навигации табов, который их переключает, а при навигации из футера, этого само собой не происходит. "Как это возможно настроить?" -- смотрите в коде своей темы

У вас скрипт отвечает за переключение. поэтому и не работает. Нужно создать скрипт или дописать этот, что бы при нажатии на Хит, он добавлял Хиту id="current" и контенту убирал display:block, а соседям ставил. Дописать нужно скрипт думаю нужно.
